# CSS3 sliding image on hover, strange spacing

Tags: android, html, css, hover

First, hello to everyone, I'm kinda new here, altough this site has helped me with lots of stuff.
Here's my problem, I've made images in 's with text behind them, so that when you hover with your pointer over it, the image slides to the side and you can read the text. Pretty simple. Now the problem that I'm having is that when I lower the screen size(eg view it on an Android), the responsive design kinda doesn't work for those images because there's some weird spacing to the left, even though the image can fit on that screen size.

Here's the site with the problem (I use it for learning purposes :)): [This](http://jigsawpotatosite.comeze.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your responsive works fine (bootstrap I guess). The problem is you have a fixed width in your `.slide1, .slide2, .slide3` that is messing the 33.3333% width of your `col-sm-4` . Basically you need to use mediaqueries to adapt your animation.

adding `overflow:hidden` to `col-sm-4` will show you better what is happening, and adding to your slides `max-width:100%`  may be the first steps to fix your web. Later your problem will be the image size